# Python: Depending on IF statement output, execute different code outside of itself

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

If my_input == "n" I want to my program to loop again, which works fine.
But if my else statement is True I dont want it to run the whole program again and just "start" at the my_input variable.

How can I achieve this?

```
def name_user_validation():
    while True:
        full_name = input("What is your name? ")
        print(f"Hello {full_name}, nice to meet you.")
        full_name.split()
        print(f"If I understood correctly, your first name is {full_name[0]} and your last name is {full_name[-1]}.")
    
        my_input = input("Is that right? (y/n) ")
        if (my_input == "y"):
            print("Great!")
            break
        elif my_input == "n":
            print("Oh no :(")
        else:
            print("Invalid input, try again.")
name_user_validation()
```

Comment: You'd need another `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another loop that doesn't terminate until user enters acceptable input.

```py
def name_user_validation():
    while True:
        full_name = input("What is your name? ")
        print(f"Hello {full_name}, nice to meet you.")
        full_name.split()
        print(f"If I understood correctly, your first name is {full_name[0]} and your last name is {full_name[-1]}.")
    
        while True:
            my_input = input("Is that right? (y/n) ")
            if (my_input == "y"):
                print("Great!")
                break
            elif my_input == "n":
                print("Oh no :(")
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input, try again.")
        if my_input == 'y':
            break
name_user_validation()
```

Edit: The program terminates only when `my_input = y`.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood your question, I would probably restructure your code a bit, so you get rid of your while loops and use recursive function calling to go back when you need to,

something like the below

```py
def name_user_validation():
    full_name = input("What is your name? ")
    print(f"Hello {full_name}, nice to meet you.")
    full_name.split()  # This line actually doesn't do anything
    print(f"If I understood correctly, your first name is {full_name[0]} and your last name is {full_name[-1]}.")

    if not accept_input():
        name_user_validation()


def accept_input():
    my_input = input("Is that right? (y/n) ")
    if my_input == "y":
        print("Great!")
        return True
    elif my_input == "n":
        print("Oh no :(")
        return False
    else:
        print("Invalid input, try again.")
        accept_input()


name_user_validation()
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I was looking for. When my_input="n" I want it to run all over again and NOT from the my_input variable. When else: I want it to rerun at the my_input variable.

Comment: I see - I have changed my reply then!

Comment: Yeah, your approche looks a lot cleaner and is easier to understand. The .split() doesnt really work right now cause its not a list. If I do "my_list = full_name.split()" for some reason it becomes a list and I get the first an last name (I thought this would work even without the variable). Right now I am just getting the first and last character of the string..

Comment: `split()` takes an argument on what to split by - so in your case you probably want to split by space, so `split(' ')`

Comment: As far as I know the deafult is space so I wouldnt need it. The issue I have is that `full_name.split()` does not work properly. It only works when I save it in a new variable like so `my_list = full_name.split()`